# how to send multiple variables from servlet as response to ajax post?

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am developing a testing system with jsp and java

At client side i have the following code:

```
        var xmlhttp = new getXmlHttpRequestObject(); //xmlhttp holds the ajax object


        function servletPost() {
            if(xmlhttp) { 
                //var txtname = document.getElementById("testForm");
                var form = $('#testForm');
                xmlhttp.open("POST","servlet/TestingController",true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServletPost;
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xmlhttp.send(form.serialize()); 
            }
        }

        function handleServletPost() {
            //var qComplexity = document.getElementsByName("qComplexity")[0].value;  


            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var respText = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    document.getElementById("fullQuestion").innerHTML = respText;
                    // here i also should change the content of the answer options
                    // so i should get from servlet multiple variables
                    // which allows me to change div contents in my jsp like as respText.question or respText.answer[0]
                } else {
                    alert("Ajax calling error");
                }                    
           }
        }
```

At server side: (my Servlet)

```
public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
 .........................................................
 .........................................................

 PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
 String complex = null;
        int categ_id = -1;
        String asked_by = null;
        String Qtext = null;
        int qid = -1;
        q_numb = 1;
        q_numb++;
        String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE complexity = '" + complexity 
                        + "'ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;";

        ResultSet r = myConnection.runQuery( sqlSelect );
        session.setAttribute("member", tempMem);

        while (r.next()) {
            complex = r.getString(5);
            categ_id = r.getInt(4);
            asked_by = r.getString(3);
            Qtext = r.getString(2);
            qid = r.getInt(1);

            String sqlA = "select * from answers where question_id = '" + qid 
                                + "' ORDER by RANDOM();";

            ResultSet result = myConnection.runQuery( sqlA );
            session.setAttribute("member", tempMem); }
```

So i need to send values of complex, Qtext, qid, categ_id and so on.
Is there any structures to send like from ajax to servlet, but visa versa? 
And how to handle sent data in client side?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). There are a myriad of free Java JSON marshallers. And JSON is natively supported by JavaScript.